# How to use a layer the same way you use function in Keras?

Tags: python, function, keras, keras-layer

I'm a student and beginner with Keras. I wonder how to use a layer such in the same way of a python function.
I want to define a layers, a Dense one, for example, and then be able to compute the image of an x given by the layer.

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: You can define your own layers, https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, take a look at [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). That way you can do something like this:

```
from keras.layers import *

# load some data into x
x = load()

dense_output = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
dropout_output = Dropout(0.3)(dense_output)   
...
```

You can do basically everything you need with Functional API. I hope this clarifies the situation for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
It is exactly what I was looking for.